# Is it possible to use chrome to emulate a horizontal screen effect of iphone?

Tags: google-chrome

I know buy press F12 button, I can emulate most common devices view effect of a webpage.

But I didn't figure out how to emulate a horizontal view effect with an iphone on chrome.

Is it possible? How to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the emulation menu, hit "screen size".

You can manually swap the height/width dimensions, or there's even a button to do it for you.

[image]